# Apache2 Referer Log - filtering my own server referers

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a custom log file that displays the referer, requested server/url, and the user agent:

```
LogFormat "\"%{Referer}i\" -> \"%v%U\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" referer2
```

This is working great, almost too great.  It dutifully reports any requests for images, css files, javascript, etc. etc.  Now I have apache2 serving several domains so I don't believe writing a filter against the domain names is very wise, as they tend to come and go.

```
"-" -> "http://www.example.com" "Firefox"
"http://www.example.com" -> "http://www.example.com/foo.css" "Firefox"
"http://www.example.com" -> "http://www.example.com/foo.jpg" "Firefox"
```

What would be the best way to filter out referer requests from example.com which may also be known as other.example.com, or foobar.com, or what-is-he-thinking.com, but all originate from the same IP?  Is this possible without having to resolve the IP address of each request?

Comment: Are you looking to do this so it's never logged? Or are you looking to do post-filtering on the logs once they're there?

Comment: I am looking to do this so it's never logged.  Ideally I'd like to see referers from external sources only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A common misunderstanding that the kind folks who attempted to help me out here is that Apache is serving a known set of domains, which it isn't.  That's why I can't just filter on a domain.

It seems my approach is not doable with just Apache, and will require a script.

Thanks guys for trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look a little more at the docs for the CustomLog directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog

I assume you've set a CustomLog for referer2. You can also append "env=" as a test to see if something will even trigger logging. Combined with a SetEnvIf directive, you can control whether or not anything gets logged to your CustomLog.

Here's an example from Apache's doc that only logs to the "gif-requests.log" file if the uri ends in .gif:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.gif$ gif-image
CustomLog gif-requests.log common env=gif-image
CustomLog nongif-requests.log common env=!gif-image
```

Comment: I could do this for each extension of css, jpg, png, etc. etc. but it would still log referers from example.org/page1.html to example.org/page2.html when I'm only trying to log external referers.  E.G: google.com to example.org/page1.html

Comment: @Clinton Request_URI is just one option to match on. "Referer" is a valid attribute: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

Comment: This makes sense if I served one domain, but as I stated in the original post I serve multiple domains.  Setting up a filter for each wouldn't be a very good use of time.

Comment: @Clinton So, you want to filter, but you don't want to set up a filter. Gotya.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I misunderstood your original request. You will most likely have to create and manage a list of referers that you want to ignore using [mod_setenvif](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html)

```
SetEnvIf Referer "example\.com" donotlog
SetEnvIf Referer "what-is-he-thinking\.com" donotlog

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log referer2 env=!donotlog
```

which will not log connections from the listed hosts. 
You could put all this in a separate file and include it into you configuration at a suitable location.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with this, the Remote_Addr is always the IP of the requester and has nothing to do with the referer.

Comment: @Clinton: I was just playing with this as I realised i misunderstood your question. I guess you're going to have to bite the bullet and make filters for each domain